# Turn off jQueryUI Button Widget

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Looking to use jQueryUI but don't want the button widget to be used in any of the other widgets(dialog, calendar etc..)

Hoping to avoid over writing styles, looking for more a javascript global "turn off this widget" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

$.fn.button = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {

```
});
```

}

Did the trick.